# Duplicate Model objects with Carrierwave in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, duplicates, carrierwave, symlink

I can duplicate an object like so:

```
  plast = Product.last
  dupobj = plast.dup
  dupobj.image = plast.image
  dupobj.save!
```

Works perfectly from the console. However when I want to populate the database, and just wrap it in a for loop:

```
  plast = Product.last
  for i in 0..50
    dupobj = plast.dup
    dupobj.image = plast.image
    dupobj.save!
  end
```

For some reason I'm getting wrong paths even though the directories are created on the disk. 
*The wrong paths are inside the model object*. Those paths on disk are correct, and files which copied there are correct too. So is it possible not to duplicate the images on the disk (and having something like symlinks functinality)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using CarrierWave Mountuploader, have a look at it's default storage strategy.
It is something like this:

```
  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

Here `model` refers to the object, your `image` is referring to.
`model.class.to_s.underscore` => Model name. Here, `Product`.
`mounted_as` => mounted attribute. Here `image`
`model.id` => id of the object => responsible for different path.

So, you must be getting the address as `/product/image/34/image.jpg`.
Configure `store_dir` method to accomplish what you have in mind.
Good luck :)

Comment: Hi kiddorails, what I didn't want to do - sorry for not mentioned this - is to change this method. But more like having an override for it for those special cases. Anyway, thanks for pointing out to this. And for my humble purposes I will just change it to "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}"

Comment: `model.id` will still create the directory with the record's id; saving duplicate image in different directory. I will look for more; you will need some different approach for symlink, because even after removing `model.id`, it will always overwrite the image (if it works for  you, then cool).